# How to specify type when calling method?

Tags: scala, types

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to make this method reusable:

```
trait T
case class A extends T
case class B extends T

def deserialize(source:Json):A = {
  source.convertTo[A]
}
```

<s>The `.convertTo[x]` method can convert into both `A` and `B`; however, at the moment this method can only produce `A`.</s> How to specify what type to convert to when calling the method?

**Clarification:**

At the moment I could do this, but it's redundant, especially when the number of `T` subclasses grow:

```
def deserialize_A_(source:Json):A = {
  source.convertTo[A]
}
def deserialize_B_(source:Json):B = {
  source.convertTo[B]
}
```

How to merge these two methods into one, so that it would handle all subclasses of `T`? (Note: presume that the nested method `convertTo` can already handle all these subclasses.)

Because it's easier to show than explain (I presume the way I wrote it won't work):

```
def deserialize(source:Json, subclassToConvertTo:SubclassOfT):SubclassOfT = {
  source.convertTo[subclassToConvertTo]
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to look at the Json structure to decide to which object to convert.

Comment: @Ashalynd this is just an abstraction of what I am trying to do. Consider that Json structure doesn't change. The method can equally produce one type or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you are using, but if you look at `convertTo` type signature, you'll see what needs to be done. For instance, spray-json has a `convertTo` method that looks like this:

```
def convertTo[T : JsonReader]: T
```

The notation `T : JsonReader` is a *context bound*, a syntactic sugar for this:

```
def convertTo[T](implicit $ev : JsonReader[T]): T
```

So, basically, you need to receive a *type parameter* (like the `T` above), and an implicit value based on that type parameter, whose type depends on what `convertTo` on the library you are using needs. Let's say it is `JsonReader`, then your method becomes:

```
def deserialize[X : JsonReader](source:Json): X = {
  source.convertTo[X]
}
```

Which you need to call like this, because `X` cannot be inferred:

```
deseralize[A](someSource)
```

If you need `X` to be a subtype of `T`, you can add that restriction like this:

```
def deserialize[X <: T : JsonReader](source:Json): X = {
  source.convertTo[X]
}
```

PS: I'd really rather you didn't use things like `T`, `A` and `B` as types in your example, since they are common identifiers for type parameters.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I have elaborated my question, sorry for being vague.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis I think it does, but since you don't think so, I'm adding an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
def deserialize[T <: A : JsonReader](source : Json) = source.convertTo[T]
```

This is just a simple matter of parametrizing the method on the type of result you want. It should be covered fairly early in any book on Scala.

See for example http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#parametricpoly

Comment: Could you briefly explain `[T <: A : JsonReader]`? I find the article you linked quite hard to understand. Any suggestions on what I should google to read up more on this?

Comment: Daniel's answer tries to explain it. I would recommend reading Programming in Scala.